# ASP.NET Core. Не устанавливается Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, webpack

Всем привет.  Пишу SPA-приложение на ASP.NET Core Vue.js. Использую webpack. В *Startup.cs* подключаю строку:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new 
WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions()
    {
        HotModuleReplacement = true
     });
```

В webpack.config.js нужно подключить свойство *optimization*, но при сборке выдает ошибку `Unknown property 'optimization'`.

Версия webpack: 4.39.0. Данная версия поддерживает свойство 'optimization'. И показывает, что данное свойство не поддерживается webpack 2, хотя в проекте установлен webpack 4. При запуске `npm run build` все работает, но при компиляции с ASP.NET Core в браузере появляется ошибка.

Также при удалении webpack с проекта, не выдается ошибка о том, что не найден webpack. Я так понял, у Visual Studio есть встроенный webpack, который используется в проекте. Как его обновить?

Comment: [посмотрите](https://romansimuta.com/blogs/blog/using-webpack-4-with-aspnet-core-21-mvc-application-to-process-es6-scripts-and-sass-styles), возможно поможет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно было обновить webpack в папке C:/Users/User/node_modules, т.к. проект использовал Webpack оттуда.